# DataTable To Entity Using Linq

Tags: linq, datatable

Hi Have This Code, I Want This Function To Return A List Of CLS_EL_ARCHIVE Objects But I Get This Error :
'CLS_EL_ARCHIVE' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 argument

```
public override IEnumerable<CLS_EL_ARCHIVE> GetAll()
    {
        DataTable DT = DAC.SelectData("SP_GET_ALL", new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@Table", "ARCHIVE") });
        List<CLS_EL_ARCHIVE> ArchiveList = new List<CLS_EL_ARCHIVE>();
        ArchiveList = DT.AsEnumerable().Select(Row => new CLS_EL_ARCHIVE
        {
            ArchiveId = Row.Field<int>("ArchiveId"),
            Label = Row.Field<string>("Label"),
            Date = Row.Field<DateTime>("Date"),
            Note = Row.Field<string>("Note")
        });
        return ArchiveList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me :) waiting for more answers

```
DataTable DT = DAC.SelectData("SP_GET_ALL", new SqlParameter[] { new SqlParameter("@Table", "ARCHIVE") });
        List<CLS_EL_ARCHIVE> ArchiveList = new List<CLS_EL_ARCHIVE>();
        ArchiveList = DT.AsEnumerable().Select(Row => new CLS_EL_ARCHIVE(Row.Field<int>("ArchiveId"), Row.Field<string>("Label"),
            Row.Field<DateTime>("Date"), Row.Field<string>("Note"))).ToList();
```